# CreateIfNotExists throwing ArgumentNullExecption

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

```
var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
cont_ref = blobClient.GetContainerReference("foo");
cont_ref.CreateIfNotExists();
```

The code was working perfectly until recentliy. Now it's throwing an **ArgumentNullException**.

**Q** The examples I've seen, demonstrate it like that. What's wrong?

**Update** The stacktrace contained in the exception reads `at System.Enum.TryParseEnum(Type enumType, String value, Boolean ignoreCase, EnumResult& parseResult)`

[image: full blown stacktrace]

Comment: Could you provide the exception message and stack trace?

Comment: @MichaelRoberson-MSFT The stacktrace stops at `CreateIfNotExists`. The exception thrown is `ArgumentNullException`. I did a little bit of research and I assume my communication with Azure gets caught by our company-proxy or/and -firewall. Are there any tools to diagnose the exact reason, why `CreateIfNotExisits` is not coming through?

Comment: The exact stack trace and exception message would be very helpful if you can provide these. What version of the storage client are you using? Fiddler is a good tool for diagnosing issues with proxies, but usually ArgumentNullException indicates a client-side failure.

Comment: @MichaelRoberson-MSFT I double-checked everything and I updated my question with the stacktrace. Additionally, I run my program on a vm within the azure cloud it's perfectly working. Something seems to get in the way if I run my program locally.