# Debugging my AzureStorage-code within Visual Studio throws SocketException

Tags: azure, azure-storage

*Note* I do not use the Storage Emulator.

If I build my solution with the configuration set to debug and then run the binaries from the command-line everything is fine and my code interacts fine with the AzureStorage.

**But**, if I debug my binaries from within the Visual-Studio a SocketException is thrown and no interaction with the AzureStorage happens.

**Q** What do I need to tweak to enable Visual-Studio to debug my code with the IDE?

**Update** I asked this question after I discovered with fiddler that Visual Studio debugs the binaries in a kind of sandbox-environment which inhibits the Azure communication.

Before discovering that, I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43803222/4090370) detailed question, which didn't receive an answer up to now. You'll find all the requested information in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43803222/4090370).

**Update1** The exception is plain and simple `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException occurred` with the corresponding stack-trace:

[image: stack-trace]

Comment: Can you share the details of your socket exception?

Comment: Have you tried to use [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) for collecting requests against your storage? Which code line throws this error, could you provide some code snippet?

Comment: I checked your previous question which talking about "CreateIfNotExists throwing ArgumentNullExecption". Does the SocketException in this issue relate to the same code? What is your project type and the version of your client library for Azure Storage you referenced?

Comment: @Bruce-MSFT AzureStorage is 8.1.3 and the project-type is Windows Application. The code is identical, it works fine when started from the command-line but fails if debugged from within Visual Studio.

Comment: I created my console application to check this issue and I could debug my application via VS 2015. I recommend you could refer to [ILSpy Debugger Preview](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/marcueusebiu/archive/2011/04/12/ilspy-debugger-preview.aspx) to isolate this issue. Additionally, what is the detailed error message from `SocketException`?

Comment: Could you see any additional information when a SocketException occured? Here is a similar issue, you could refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31637497/how-to-handle-socket-exception).